# Vector space and basis

Tags: linear-algebra

How should I go and solve this problem? Any hints or insights would be appreciated.

Let $V$ be a vector space.

- (a) Show that $x$, $y$ $\in$ $V$ form a basis if and only if $x$ + $y$, $x$ - $y$ form a basis.
- (b) Show that $x$,$y$,$z$ $\in$ $V$ form a basis if and only if $x$ + $y$, $y$ + $z$, $z$ + $x$ form a basis.

Comment: Looks like this problem wants you to have a look at what happens if x and y are parallel vectors. What would happen to their sum/difference in that case?

Comment: Note that this becomes false, if $1+1=0$ in the underlying field of the vector space.

Comment: I feel like I might have to prove that the two linear combinations of x and y are a basis if they fulfill the basic property of uniqueness if I  get their sum/difference, but I'm not sure...

Comment: **Hint:** If you have a basis $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ and some vectors $u_1,\dotsc,u_n$, then $u_1,\dotsc,u_n$ is also a basis if and only if each of $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ is contained in the span of $u_1,\dotsc,u_n$ (why?). This is easily checked in your problem.

Comment: A basis must be linearly independent and span the space. In (a) if two vectors span the space it is two dimensional so if two other vectors are a basis they must just be linearly independent. Prove it by contradiction, show that $x, y$ linearly dependent is equivalent to $x + y, x - y$ being linearly dependent. Proceed similarly for (b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides my comment suggesting a constructive proof, here's a neater but more advanced solution for (a): you can follow the same steps for (b).

Let $x, y$ be a basis and let $T$ be the linear transformation represented in this basis by $\begin {pmatrix}
1 &1\\
1 & -1
\end {pmatrix}$

Then the vectors $x$ and $y$ are respectiveley mapped as

$T(x) = $
$\begin {pmatrix}
1 &1\\
1 & -1
\end {pmatrix}$
$\begin {pmatrix}
1\\
0
\end {pmatrix}
=
\begin {pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end {pmatrix} = x + y$

$T(y) = $
$\begin {pmatrix}
1 &1\\
1 & -1
\end {pmatrix}$
$\begin {pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end {pmatrix}
=
\begin {pmatrix}
1\\
-1
\end {pmatrix} = x - y$

Since the determinant of the matrix $=-2$ and $\ne 0$ then it is invertible, consequently $T$ is invertible and so $T$ and its inverse $T^{-1}$ are isomorphisms and therefore map bases to bases.